# httpResponse one or two characters shorter

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, httpresponse

I'm writing a wcf webservice. It will mostly be focused on json and xml, but I need a string return in 2 cases.

I'm setting up the test:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
      UriTemplate = "test")]
  string BasicString();
```

I'm cheating the respons, by sending string back myself, bypassing the standard json return.

```
   protected string BasicString()
   {
       string text = "ok";
       HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
       //response.AddHeader("Content-Length", "");
       response.ContentType = "text/html";
       //response.BufferOutput = true;
       response.Output.Write(text);
       //response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
       response.End();
       return string.Empty;
   }
```

The return on most browsers is "OK". However on google chrome, and some others, it takes of the last character. It reads ... "O". I'm running it on my local IIS.

If i put it on a hosted IIS, than it returns "OK", and sometimes 329 Encoding error.

Where do i need to start looking for it to return "OK" in all cases?

Headers? I've tried disabling some of the lines above, or different values already.

HTTP sniffer gives me the following:
Request:

> GET /Service/Test.svc/string HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost Connection:
>   keep-alive Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36 Accept-Encoding:
>   gzip,deflate,sdch Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Response:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Encoding: gzip Vary:
>   Accept-Encoding Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Sun, 16 Jun 2013 12:19:00 GMT
>
> 70
>   ��������`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{���{���;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"���

Comment: If you open web developer tools then what does request look like, can you post the actual request/response object as it appears on the web developer tools?

Comment: Updated the post with the request information. The response looks "well" messed up.

Comment: "I'm cheating the response" - please don't. If you're using WCF, there will be some modules for that framework inside the ASP.NET pipeline. If you want to return a "raw" (non-JSON, non-XML) string, use the [raw programming model in WCF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web.aspx) instead. And for your last comment, the response isn't (necessarily) messed up, it's gzip-encoded, which is why you can't understand it.

Comment: The text in HTTP is UTF-8 and Visual Studio uses UTF-16 by default. Your "ok" response -- when looked at as UTF-8....equates to the letter "o" and a null terminator (the value zero). Some browsers just use the status code value and print their own description, but -- if you are going to try to mess around with the response, you should bear in mind that the encoding is relevant -- not just as a header value, but also -- the text you are generating must be properly encoded, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment of Carlos lead to the answer.

Use IO.stream as an return type, instead of string.

```
[ServiceContract] public class RawService {
    [OperationContract, WebGet]
    public System.IO.Stream GetValue()
    {
        string result = "Hello world";
        byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
        return new MemoryStream(resultBytes);
    } }
```

Comment: The sample was writing to the Output stream already -- the issue was that it was writing an UTF-16 encoded string instead of an UTF-8 encoded one, like your nice code does.